# Gamecenter code not working at all, always printing false.

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am learning about how to put Gamecenter into an app, using Xcode, Swift, and SpriteKit. Whenever I play the iOS Simulator, nothing pops up, (either a "sign-in" screen should pop up, or a "Welcome Back" screen should pop up) and the console prints "false". I been trying to figure out why it is not working. (Oh and if this helps, I am right now running the OS X Beta for El Capitan) Someone please help!

Here is the code:

```
import GameKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    authenticateLocalPlayer()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


func authenticateLocalPlayer(){


    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            //These 2 lines are the only parts that have been changed
            let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
            vc.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
        }
    }
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: AFAIK if you canceled the login window 3-5 times , iOS will stop popping it without any information. Now if you want that window again try to reset your simulator or enable GC for your app from GC app (in device).

Comment: @HarvantS. I have found it! Thank you! It worked like a charm!

Comment: @HarvantS. I have one more question, so everything is half working half not working. So the code works and the gamecenter screen pops up, those game center "Bubbles" pop up, and thats it, nothing else. No login screen no nothing, the "Bubbles" just stay there, and I can't do anything, I can't even cancel out. Do you know why? If this helps, I reset the content and settings of the iOS simulator, as you said before.

Comment: Your code seems right. Probably GameKit is not working well.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help! @HarvantS.